# How to pin my page to start up menu in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have a detail page that user has navigated to and on that page, I have an application bar Pin button that enable user pin that page to the start up menu. Therefore, when user press start up menu on his phone the next time, he will see the icon representing the page that he pinned previousely in the starup menu. If he presses it, he will be directed to that page.

I have googled around but there was not any clue? Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other name for pinned pages is Secondary Tile.
To create a secondary tile in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app, check this quick start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868249.aspx

To create a secondary tile in Windows Phone 8.0 app, use ShellTile.Create().
Check this link for an example:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-add-and-remove-secondary-tiles-in-windows-phone-apps